# problems with PostgreSQL sum(case when count > 0) over partition week-of-year and hour

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL version 9.4.18

The following is a query that's returning unexpected results for non_zero_year_count and percent_years_count_not_zero:

Table data:
From 1988-2018 but in sqlfiddle test database have just done 2016-2018 with the following table. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/34289a/19

```
CREATE TABLE ltg_data
("intensity" int, "time" timestamp with time zone, "lon" int, "lat" int)

(200, '2018-06-23 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-24 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-25 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-24 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-25 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-24 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-25 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-24 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-25 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-25 17:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2018-06-25 17:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2017-06-25 19:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2017-06-25 20:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2017-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2017-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2017-06-24 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2017-06-24 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2017-06-23 21:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2017-06-23 21:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2017-06-24 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2017-06-24 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2017-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2017-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2016-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2016-06-25 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2016-06-25 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2016-06-27 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2016-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446),
(200, '2016-06-26 07:19:00', -122.109, 42.9446)
```

So the following query should return some basic statistics about the table data. The challenge, I think, is trying to partition over week-of-year and hour while incorporating the year somehow. The errant data involves the portion of the query that's trying to determine the number of years where there is a count > 0 for a week-of-the-year and hour (woyhh). Here's the query and functions (woy functions to factor in leap year for standardization year to year) that the query utilizes. I'm using generate series because I want a full year's worth of woyhh even if there are no counts in a certain woyhh.

**Functions:**

```
create or replace function IsLeapYear(int)
returns boolean as $$
select $1 % 4 = 0 and ($1 % 100 <> 0 or $1 % 400 = 0)
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT; 

create or replace function f_woyhh(timestamp with time zone)
returns int language plpgsql as $$
declare
currentYear int = extract (year from $1);
LeapYearShift int = 1 + (IsLeapYear(currentYear) and $1 > make_date  (currentYear, 2, 28))::int;
begin
return CONCAT(((extract(doy from $1)::int)- LeapYearShift) / 7+ 1, to_char   ($1, 'HH24'));
end;
$$;
```

**Query:**

```
WITH
CTE_Dates
AS
(
SELECT  f_woyhh(d) as dt


    ,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d::timestamp) AS dtYear from
generate_series(timestamp '2016-01-01', timestamp '2018-12-31', interval '1 hour') as d
    -- full range of possible dates
)
,CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts
AS
(
SELECT
f_woyhh(time) as dt
    ,time
    ,count(*) AS ct
FROM
    ltg_data
    GROUP BY ltg_data.time
)

,CTE_FullStats
AS
(
SELECT
    CTE_dates.dt as woyhh

    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CTE_Dates.dtYear)  AS years_count
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts.ct > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER   (PARTITION BY CTE_Dates.dt) AS nonzero_year_count
,100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts.ct > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   OVER (PARTITION BY CTE_Dates.dt)
    / COUNT(DISTINCT CTE_Dates.dtYear) as percent_years_count_not_zero
FROM
    CTE_Dates
    LEFT JOIN CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts ON CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts.dt = CTE_Dates.dt
    GROUP BY CTE_dates.dt, CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts.ct, CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts.dt
    )

SELECT
woyhh
,nonzero_year_count
,years_count
,percent_years_count_not_zero
FROM
CTE_FullStats
WHERE woyhh::text like '26%'
    GROUP BY woyhh,   years_count, nonzero_year_count,     percent_years_count_not_zero
    ORDER BY  woyhh
```

**Unexpected results:**

```
woyhh | nonzero_year_count | years_count| percent_years_count_not_zero
2605  | 0                  | 3          | 0
2606  | 0                  | 3          | 0
2607  | 5                  | 3          | 200
2608  | 0                  | 3          | 0
2609  | 0                  | 3          | 0
```

The portions of the results that aren't working for woyhh 2607 are nonzero_year_count, which should be 3 because there are only 3 years of data and there is a count in week 26 and hour 07 of each of those years (any day after the 24th of the month is on week 26). Also, the percent_years_count_not_zero should be 100%, not 200%. 100% is the maximum desired percent_years_count_not_zero.

**Desired results:**

```
woyhh | nonzero_year_count | years_count| percent_years_count_not_zero
2605  | 0                  | 3          | 0
2606  | 0                  | 3          | 0
2607  | 3                  | 3          | 100
2608  | 0                  | 3          | 0
2609  | 0                  | 3          | 0
```

So I think the main problem lies with this portion of the query:

```
,SUM(CASE WHEN CTE_WeeklyHourlyCounts.ct > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER  (PARTITION BY CTE_Dates.dt) AS nonzero_year_count
```

If I'm partitioning over woyhh, but this isn't sufficient because I need to factor in the years. It's like I need to group year in there somehow to determine if a woyhh has occurred in a year, then count it as one and no more for that year. I've tried incorporating year but have run into even stranger results.

I hope this clarifies my question some. I've included an updated sqlfiddle below to replicate the data/query I'm using for the test table. Thanks for any help!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/34289a/19

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, and there's too much going on in your SQLFiddle to figure out what your problem even is, let alone what code is causing it. Please edit your question to show *in the question* (not as a link) the minimum example data required to show the problem, your query, your output given the example data and desired output.

Comment: @Bohemian I edited the question further to limit the amount of data, display the data in the question, and simplify the query. I also tried to focus the question on the main problem after continuing to test/examine the query. There's a good bit of data, but it's needed to show the problem clearly. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Bohemian I have posted as another question. I've refined it the best I can to include the minimum amount of data possible...and data is inside the question and not just a link. I've been stuck trying to figure this out for a few weeks now, so hopefully the question is worded well enough so the experts can understand my problem.